# copying resource to sdcard gives a damaged file in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to move a raw resource (it is a zip file) from the app to SD card using this code:

```
void copyFile() throws IOException {
    File dest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest + "/file.zip");

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

However, when I check the file on the sd card I get the message:
"The archive is either in an unknown format or damaged"

Why is the file not being copied properly?

Comment: When creating the destination file use the approprate constructor `new File(dest, "file.zip")`.. has it transfered the whole file?

Comment: the file is being transferred in whole, however I noticed that the file on the SD card is a bit larger than the resource. Also, how do I used File(). Since the resource is being streamed I need to write the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some little modifications on your code:

```
File dest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file);
// Used the File-constructor
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dest, "file.zip"));

// Transfer bytes from in to out
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
try {
    // A little more explicit
    while ( (len = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1){
         out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
} finally {
    // Ensure the Streams are closed:
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

This one worked for me (not on Android but on a normal computer). The modifications I made where:

- I used the [`File`-constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) for the [`FileOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29).
- I used a `try-catch`-block to ensure that the Streams are getting
  closed, even when there is an error/exception while reading/writing.
- I used the more explicit [`read`-method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) (which is basically the
  same as yours) because I feel better when I tell him what to do.

As I said above, I tried it on my computer and it worked. Proof:

```
[luke@KeksDose Downloads]$ md5sum quick_action.zip 
4e45fa08f24e971961dd60c3e81b292d  quick_action.zip
[luke@KeksDose Downloads]$ md5sum quick_action_copy.zip 
4e45fa08f24e971961dd60c3e81b292d  quick_action_copy.zip
```

Comment: worked perfectly. Thank you. Just one note though in case someone else uses this code. Make sure that you check the card is not mounted. Follow this topic for more info and sample code: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/141016