# How to add sd-card's files in app?

Tags: android, file, apk, sd-card

I need add some files in my application and this files must be unpacked to sd card after application install. Is it possible on Android? How I can to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the file to your resources/raw directory.  When the application runs, you can check for the existence of the target file.  If it doesn't exist, [unpack and write to the SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7215369/974369):

```
File dest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file);
// Used the File-constructor
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dest, "file.zip"));

// Transfer bytes from in to out
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
try {
    // A little more explicit
    while ( (len = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1){
         out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
} finally {
    // Ensure the Streams are closed:
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: Please, do not write at the storage root! use: /Android/data/<package_name>/files/ see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal